# Display the html returned by fetch()

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I am using a web app to submit some form data to an API. The process is as follows:

1. Enter data in a html form
2. When the user presses a button I use javascript to collect the form data and create a JSON string out of it
3. Using fetch() I post that JSON to an API endpoint
4. The API server returns a redirect to a new page (complete html document)

What I would like to achieve is that when the fetch request completes the user would be redirected to the page that was received from the API server. I tried searching for this however I couldn't find anything since most examples are for storing the response in a variable and doing something with it.

This needs to be done in vanilla Javascript, since it is an embedded system and I would like to use as little dependencies as possible.

Comment: Do you have a way to change the response? This is really a bad practise. You would need to remove all of the html from the current page and then replace it with the one from the response.
In this case it is better not to use fetch api ajax request in general but just use simple url redirect.

Comment: I could modify the API response, since I am building that also however I would prefer to keep it like it is. What I am trying to achieve is basically the default form submit behavior, I just need to put in a custom body for the POST request (JSON instead of form data). Is it possible to do a URI redirect to a POST request (with a custom body) in javascript? The only way of doing a post redirect I've found so far is submitting a dummy form and specifying the url as action parameter in the form. However that doesn't allow you to set a custom body.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not what AJAX is made for. I suggest you to either stick to regular form submission or change the response.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will work for you.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>site</h1>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
        const res = await fetch('/index2.html');
        const text = await res.text();
        document.open();
        document.write(text);
        document.close();
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Alexander works, however as Nikola already said it's not really considered good practice to clear current html and replace it.
At the end I opted for a different approach. I collected all the data from the original form, created a json string out of it and then dynamically created another form with only one field to which I assigned the value of json string and then submitted this new form. This way I could achieve the redirect behavior of the  element while making minimum modifications on the server side.